# Where can various (playable) characters be found during the Lantern Rite event?

Tags: genshin-impact

During the current Lantern Rite event in Genshin Impact, you can find several playable characters dotted around the world (at least you can after completing the "Sky-Grazers, Land-Walkers" quest). Interacting with these characters will give you some voice lines related to the Lantern Rite.

So far I've come across the following characters:

- Xiangling (inside Wanmin Restaurant)
- Hu Tao (standing next to the notice board at Wangsheng Funeral Parlor)
- Ningguang (inside the Jade Chamber)
- Ganyu (next to the teleport waypoint on Mount Aocang)

Are there any other playable characters that can be found in the world that give Lantern Rite-related voice lines? If so, where can they be found? I had a brief look around the Alcor (for Beidou) and Wangshu Inn (for Xiao) but couldn't seem to find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Courtesy of various sources, this is the list of where to find every character.

After Event quest part 1:

- **Hu Tao** - Wangsheng Funeral Parlor
- **Ningguang** - Jade Chamber
- **Xiangling** - Wanmin Restaurant

After Event quest part 2:

- **Xiao** - Pervases’ Temple (may also require you to complete the Starsnatcher return quest?)
- **Beidou & Xinyan**  - Liyue North Entrance Bridge
- **Yanfei** - Yujing Terrace
- **Shenhe** - Liyue Dock
- **Legendary adeptibeast** (formerly known as Ganyu)- Mt. Aocang
- **Qiqi** & Changsheng - Qingce Village

After Event quest part 3:

- **Chongyun & Xingqiu** - Qingce Village
- **Yun Jin** - Qingce Village
- **Zhongli** - Third Round Knockout
- **Keqing** - Jade Chamber

Comment: Can confirm Xiao doesnt need to have finished the Starsnatcher quest. I happened on him there while doing the quest. Was confused that he was seemingly unrelated to the quest at that point lol.

Comment: @Fredy31 So, was he there both as an NPC during the quest (you meet him at the temple) and on the hill near the temple (Lantern rite appearance, he speaks about the Rite)?

Comment: Is there a moment when he is there simply as an NPC? Can't remember. Think at most he shows up for a cutscene then leaves, and he's never just there waiting for you to talk to him. So no, i don't think there is a point where you got 2 xiaos just chilling next to eachother.